# RavenDB indexes error "Could not find index named"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb, indexing

I am new to using RavenDB and trying to get indexes to work in a simple MVC3 app which allows users to enter geographic locations. I have two models, a UserModel and a LocationModel. The LocationModel stores the UserId when saved and I am trying to create an index on this.

```
public class Locations_ByUser : AbstractIndexCreationTask<LocationModel>
    {
        public Locations_ByUser()
        {
            Map = locations => from location in locations
                            select new { location.UserId };

        }
    }
```

I am registering the index with the following code

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            //ADD THE MODEL BINDER FOR LIST TO STRING
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TestAPI.Models.LocationModel), new TestAPI.Classes.LocationModelBinder());

            //INIT THE STORE, DO ONCE PER APP START
            TestAPI.Classes.DataDocumentStore.Initialize(); 

            //SET THE INDEXES
            IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Locations_ByUser).Assembly, TestAPI.Classes.DataDocumentStore.Instance);
        }
```

However, when i try to call the index from the mvc app

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var result = this.DocumentSession.Query<LocationModel>("Locations_ByUser").ToList();
            foreach (var userid in result)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(userid);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

it returns the following error

> Could not find index named: Locations_ByUser

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this before and could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index in RavenDB will actually be named: "Locations/ByUser" when it's generated.

If you open up the Raven Studio you can see this under the index's. The _ is replaced with /

Also you don't need to specify the string value, you can write your query like:

```
var result = this.DocumentSession.Query<LocationModel, Locations_ByUser>().ToList();
```

Comment: You are awesome! You managed to solve two problems for me. I couldn't figure out how to get the Raven Studio to load in embedded and I tracked it down thanks to this post (as well as getting my index to work). I must have missed the naming convention in the documentation. Do you happen to know where I could find it?

Comment: I don't think the index naming is mentioned in the documentation, I think it was a change made during version 4xx. Not entirely sure. I took a quick look and couldn't find it.